# Can't uninstall Intel RealSense due to source file invalid

Tags: intel, uninstallation, realsense

I'm trying to uninstall Intel Realsense SDK and every single uninstall attempt fails and this appears:

"The integrity check failed
Source file is incorrect/invalid
intel_rs_sdk_runtime_ia32_track3d_metaio_6_0_21_6598.msi"

This is a translation from the Dutch error message. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are still experiencing this error, you can try the following:

1. Go to the Intel® RealSense™ SDK​ Developer Zone. 
   (https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-realsense-sdk/download)
2. Scroll down to the SDK Components Download and click Download.
3. Complete Product Registration if Required
4. After Registering, you will receive a Serial Key and a Download options, chose the option that best suites your needs. The requested serial key during the download option will be the Serial Key you received during registration, not the camera serial.
5. You should be given an option to uninstall.